# Stylus color conversion functions (hue, saturation)

Tags: css, stylus

How can I change the hue and increase the saturation of a hex color value with Stylus?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do you can mash everything like `hue(saturation(#00c, 50%), 80deg)` or vice-versa or do bit by bit like @Dor-Ron said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stylus actually has built-in functions for these.
Based off the docs [hue](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#huecolor-value), [saturation](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#saturationcolor-value):

The following should work:

`hue(#00c, 90deg)`

`saturation(#00c, 50%)`